# Automatically indent within XML tag in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code

I'm in the process of migrating from Sublime Text to Visual Studio Code. There's one feature that I'm missing and have been unable to work out how to achieve.

In Sublime Text, if I'm editing XML and have the cursor between a start/end tag (where the cursor is represented by `|`:

```
  <p>|</p>
```

Hitting enter inserts a blank line between the tags and indents like so:

```
  <p>
    |
  </p>
```

In Visual Studio code, the same action just inserts a newline and indents the closing tag:

```
   <p>
  |</p>
```

Is there any way of achieving the same effect as in Sublime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: There seems to be no way to achieve this in Visual Studio Code outside of creating a plugin.

As it happens, I've switched to Atom, which seems to have made *much* better choices in this area (for my purposes at least).